# How to recover individuals meeting certain conditions in at least one column?

Tags: r

```
ID<-c(1:10)
M1<-c("A","C","V","X","V","Z","K","SA","KS","B")
M2<-c("A","H","D","K","DEL","QS","L","SA","OOB","NO")
M3<-c("A","C","V","X","V","Z","K","SA","NC","RG")
M4<-c("ABS","JC","VJ","TE","DEL","GJ","FH","QM","SF","X")
M5<-c("ER","DU","OD","KZ","GZ","ZB","DEL","SA","DEL","WX")

mydata<-data.frame(ID,M1,M2,M3,M4,M5)
```

Here is a representation of my dataset. Ten individuals with five temporal units of follow-up.
I want at first to retrieve the ID of each individual that has `"DEL"` as observation, then suppress it. In my case, it must be the individuals `5`, `7`, and `9`

Comment: What are you expecting the output to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to get the `ID` alone

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>%
     filter(if_any(starts_with('M'), ~ . == 'DEL')) %>%
     pull(ID)
```

-output

```
[1] 5 7 9
```

Or if we need the subset of rows

```
mydata %>%
    filter(if_any(starts_with('M'), ~ . == 'DEL'))
```

-output

```
 ID M1  M2 M3  M4  M5
1  5  V DEL  V DEL  GZ
2  7  K   L  K  FH DEL
3  9 KS OOB NC  SF DEL
```

---

Or use `which` with `arr.ind`

```
unique( which(mydata[-1] == 'DEL', arr.ind = TRUE)[,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) package.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata_subset <- mydata %>% filter(across(everything(), ~ !grepl('DEL', .)))
```